# Call a function that is exported within file in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, export

With ES6 `export` syntax you can export a function such as:

```
export default async function main(){
  // do some stuff
}

main();
```

However when I run it using the syntax above, I receive the error below:

`ReferenceError: main is not defined`

How can I run this function while exporting it at the same time?

Comment: What you have should work, but there is a bug in Babel: https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/3786

Comment: Want to use that response an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/3786, you may try like this:

```
async function main() {
  // do some stuff
}
export { main as default }
main();
```